# Category Archive Page

Tags: ee2, categories

EE 2.7.2 Build20131008

I am fairly new to expression engine and having a little bit of trouble getting this to work out the way I need it.

I am trying to create a category archive page. Here is the code I have so far:

```
{exp:channel:category_heading}
<h2>Careers in {category_name}</h2>
{/exp:channel:category_heading}
{exp:channel:categories channel="careers" category="{category_id}" style="linear"}
<ul>
{exp:channel:entries channel="careers" category="{category_id}" orderby="date" sort="desc" disable="member_data" dynamic="no"}
<li>
<a href="{url_title_path='careers'}">{title}: ({career_location})</a>
</li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>         
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

The issue I have is that is doesn't seem to be pulling the "category_id" in the channel:entries tag. So I currently have 2 posts, both are assigned to 2 categories. So it actually renders a list of 4 posts, instead of just 2.

**More Details**

Here is a full layout of how things are setup:

Careers Channel with 2 category groups - location and department.

_desktop/careers pulls the careers listing. Currently have a select/dropdown on that page.

```
<form name="catmenu" action="">
<select name="selcat" onchange="location=document.catmenu.selcat.options[document.catmenu.selcat.selectedIndex].value;">
    <option value="">--Select Category--</option>
    {exp:channel:categories channel="careers" category_group="2" style="linear"}
        <option value="{path='careers/listing'}/{category_id}">{category_name}</option>
    {/exp:channel:categories}
</select>
</form>
```

I created the careers/listing template as a "landing page" for when a category is selected. So lets say you select "Jobsville, NY" from the dropdown, it points to the careers/listing template with this URL:

```
domain.com/careers/listing/C37
```

Jobsville category id is "37". I can't figure out how to get it to spit out /careers/listing/category_name either.

On this listing page is where I have the code from the first part of my question. I currently have 2 posts.

- Post 1 - assigned to location 1 and department 2
- Post 2 - assigned to location 2 and department 2

The listing page is showing 2 copies of each post - not limiting the list to the category that I am currently viewing.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add an example url you are using for the page?  If it is a category page you do not need to specify the category as a parameter in your entry.  It will be picked up dynamically.

Comment: More details added.

Answer (score 0):

On your `listing` template try simply omitting the `category` and `dynamic` parameters, like so:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="careers" orderby="date" sort="desc" disable="member_data"}
```

If you want to switch from category IDs to category URL titles try this:

```
<option value="{path='careers/listing'}/category/{category_url_title}">{category_name}</option>
```

[Documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/add-ons/channel/categories.html#category-url-title)

Comment: Ok, that did a few different things. Removing the category and dynamic parameters made the listing page show a long list of the same entry over and over again.

On the URL snippet, the URL now looks like `domain.com/careers/listing/C37/category/cityname`. How can I get it to just replace the C37 with the cityname?

Comment: {path='careers/listing'}/category/{category_url_title} gives you domain.com/careers/listing/C37/category/cityname ? Really? Are you sure you don't still have {category_id} in there?

Comment: Here is my full code for that drop down

`<form name="catmenu" action="">
    <select name="selcat" onchange="location=document.catmenu.selcat.options[document.catmenu.selcat.selectedIndex].value;">
        <option value="">--Select Category--</option>
        {exp:channel:categories channel="careers" category_group="2" style="linear"}
 <option value="{path='careers/listing'}/category/{category_url_title}">{category_name}</option>
        {/exp:channel:categories}
    </select>
</form>`

Comment: Also still have the issue of that entries snippet looping and repeating the same single entry over and over.